# http.post() is not sending the request and get error : "Invalid token specified"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular CLI and I want to write login component in Angular but when I make a post request the angular http is not sending the request to the server and as output, I received this error message in the console and any request has not been sent to the server:

```
InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified"}
InvalidTokenError
    at Object../node_modules/jwt-decode/lib/index.js (http://localhost:26000/vendor.js:497368:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:26000/runtime.js:77:30)
    at Object../src/app/authentication/auth.service.ts (http://localhost:26000/main.js:584:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:26000/runtime.js:77:30)
    at Object../src/app/authentication/auth-guard.service.ts (http://localhost:26000/main.js:400:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:26000/runtime.js:77:30)
    at Object../src/app/modules/hub-administration-tool/hub-administration-tool.routing.module.ts (http://localhost:26000/main.js:12909:92)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:26000/runtime.js:77:30)
    at Object../src/app/modules/hub-administration-tool/hub-administration-tool.module.ts (http://localhost:26000/main.js:12697:98)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:26000/runtime.js:77:30)
```

here is authentication component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import decode from 'jwt-decode';




interface TokenResponse {
  access_token: string
}

export interface TokenPayload {
  username: string
  password: string
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService,
    private http: HttpClient) { }


  public login (user: TokenPayload) {

    const base = this.http.post<any>(`//localhost:25000/auth/login`, {   username: user.username,    password: user.password  },{ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') })
    const request = base.pipe(
        map((data : TokenResponse) => {
            console.log({data});
             if (data.access_token) {
                console.log(data.access_token)
             }
            return data
        })
    )
    return request
}

}
```

and here is login component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService, TokenPayload } from '../authentication/auth.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators  } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient,HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  credentials: TokenPayload = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
}

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  @Input() layoutTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private http : HttpClient
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {



  }


  login() {
    this.authService.login(this.credentials).subscribe( //get username and password from Html file
      () => {
          console.log("DONE" );
      },
      err => {
          console.error(err)
      }
  )


}

}
```

packages.Json

```
{
  "name": "administration-hub",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 26000 --poll=2000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "3.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "1 - 2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "2 - 3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.2.704",
    "@types/cross-storage": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cross-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^6.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

when you get result in your service that is coming from server and carry token, it is an object. so, you should go inside the object and extract the token. in your code, token is not defined, so you get the error. in your component :

```
     const base = this.http.post<any>(`//localhost:25000/auth/login`, {   username: 
       user.username,    password: user.password  },{ headers: new 
      HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') })
           const request = base.pipe(
         map((data : TokenResponse) => {
           console.log({data});    // is the respond object

           console.log(data['_body'].token) //// your token is here

          return data
              })
                )
            return request
            }
```

i hope it works

Comment: It did not work. Because the data is not sent to the server!!! I don't know why! I used these packages.